# How to modularize Rails code?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

Basically, I'm in the process of writing a website that interfaces with many popular websites (Facebook, Twitter, Youtube etc). My principal objective will be the same, however the way I accomplish my objective will be different for every site I support, because their layout is different and because I'll have to script my requests based off the workings of their website.

The user chooses which particular website they want to use the service I offer for (i.e. do they want to use it for facebook, or for twitter, etc). And they can only choose 1 of these websites per request of my service.

I'm wondering what a good design principal/practice is when it comes to Rails modularization (this is my first Rails project, I've had lots of exposure to other languages though). Basically, the way I see it is, a user will submit their request to my controller, which will check what site they chose. My controller will then "load" a particular module (i.e. if they chose facebook, it would load the facebook module), which will contain all of the code for dealing with Facebook requests. It will then call this code in whatever way necessary, and serve results to the user.

So basically, my question is really coming down to best practice and design principles in regards to Rails. How do you think a good way to separate my code is in this instance? Should I have a class for every site I support (facebook, twitter, etc)? This is the only real option I can think of (because I'm not very familiar with Rails), however I'm sure there would be a better option, so I can limit the amount of code redundancy, as the goal of each class will be the same, it'll just be a different technique to obtaining the goal (i.e. the method names will be the same for every class, etc).

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looks like the strategy pattern to me. You could do it like this (not sure where to put it in Rails).

```
require "delegate"

class Youtube
  def open_connection
    #code to open connection with youtube
  end

  def do_stuff    
    puts "doing stuff on Youtube" 
  end

  def close_connection
    #code to close connection
  end
end

class Facebook
  #define the same methods here
end


class Service < SimpleDelegator
  def hello
    puts "Hello, I stole most of my methods from #{__getobj__}"
  end
end


s = Service.new(Youtube.new)
s.hello     #=> Hello, I stole most of my methods from #<Youtube:0xb7724b1c>
s.do_stuff  #=> doing stuff on Youtube
```

Comment: Thanks steenslag, that sounds perfect :)! If anyone knows where this sort of thing would go in rails, I'm all set. My only guess is in the /lib directory, however I'm probably wrong.

Answer (score 1):

This is a subjective question, it depends on how many features would you like to add, and how complicated they are. Regarding to using external apis, i'm pretty sure there are api connection gems for each. If you don't like them, you can use just [`ActiveResource`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveResource/Base.html) which works great with REST apis. Also I recommend watching these screencasts about `ActiveResource`.

- http://railscasts.com/episodes/94-activeresource-basics
- http://railscasts.com/episodes/95-more-on-activeresource

Regarding to your application structure, I would use [namespaces](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#controller-namespaces-and-routing) to keep your controllers and routes well separated on each module.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. So, would I use controllers in namespaces? Say for instance, the following:

support_websites_controller.rb:

namespace Facebook do
end

namespace Youtube do
end

etc?

Comment: It depends on what your site is about. If you have similar features for each api namespaces could help you to identify your controllers. For example if you have different preferences for each api, you will have multiple `preferences_controller.rb` in different namespaces. One in facebook namespace, and one in twitter namespace etc..